# Method to find inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{k} \sin(k)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I wanted to find the inverse Fourier transform of $\tilde f(k)=\frac{1}{k}\sin(k)$. I found a similar question here: [Calculating the Inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}k}\sin k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603550/calculating-the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-frac1-sqrt2-pik-sin-k), but I have been asked to do this using contour integration (which isn't mentioned in the answers to that question). My problem with this is if you take $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde f(k) e^{ikx} dk$, then this has no poles, and so nowhere to calculate a residue. Normally I'd just use a semi-circular contour, however in this case I don't think that the integral along the arc would go to $0$. Whichever contour I choose, the total integral along that contour will be $0$. This would mean that I'd get something like "the integral I want" + "something extra which isn't $0$" $= 0$. I think my main problem is finding this "something extra" - what contour should I use? Could I use the expected answer somehow to help choose that?

Comment: A quick way to find the answer is to notice that if $f(x) = \int \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}{\rm d}k$ then $f'(x) = i\int \sin(k) e^{ikx}{\rm d}k = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\pi\left[ \delta(x+1) - \delta(x-1)\right]$ by the [Fourier representation of the delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History) and so by integration you'll get that $f(x)$ is constant when $x\in (-1,1)$ and $0$ otherwise. If you want a rigorous derivation and don't know how to justify all the steps then you can always just go back and show that the Fourier transform of the answer you get equals $\sin(k)/k$.

Comment: @Winther Hans, the OP states "I have been asked to do this using contour integration."  So while the comment provides a way forward, it does address the specific need herein.  ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)}{k}e^{ikx}\,dk=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ik}-e^{-ik}}{k}e^{ikx}\,dk \tag1$$

Observe that for each of the principal value integrals

$$I_{\pm}(x)=\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\pm ik}}{k}e^{ikx}\,dk\right)=\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ ik(x\pm 1)}}{k}\,dk\right)$$

the integrand has a pole at $k=0$.  To evaluate these integrals, we analyze the contour integrals

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C}\frac{e^{iz(x\pm 1)}}{z}\,dz&=\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{ik(x\pm 1)}}{k}\,dk+\int_{\epsilon}^{R} \frac{e^{ik(x\pm 1)}}{k}\,dk\\\\
&+\int_{\text{sgn}(x\pm 1)\pi}^0 \frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_0^{\text{sgn}(x\pm 1)\pi}\frac{e^{i R e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 2
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, the last integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ tends to $0$.  As $\epsilon\to 0$, the third integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ tends to $-\text{sgn}(x\pm 1)\pi$.  Therefore, we have

$$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ ik(x+ 1)}-e^{ik(x-1)}}{k}\,dk\right)=\text{sgn}(x+1)\pi-\text{sgn}(x-1)\pi=\begin{cases}2\pi &,|x|<1\\\\0&,|x|>1\\\\\pi&,|x|=1\end{cases} \tag 3$$

Substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)}{k}e^{ikx}\,dk=\begin{cases}\pi &,|x|<1\\\\0&,|x|>1\\\\\pi/2&,|x|=1\end{cases} $$

Comment: Why are we allowed to use principal value integrals here? In general, where are we allowed to use them? Though I have been taught that they're useful, I haven't been told when we should use them.

Comment: The original integral converges - no PV required.  So, we're free to evaluate it as if it were a PV integral (this is just a special case of the improper integral).  In doing so, we can write  $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{\sin(k)e^{ikx}}{k}\,dk+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k)e^{ikx}}{k}\,dk\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{ik(x+1)}}{k}\,dk+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik(x+1)}}{k}\,dk-\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{ik(x-1)}}{k}\,dk+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik(x-1)}}{k}\,dk\right)$$